# Mobile Device (Android) Encryption

Tags: android, encryption, android-permissions, mobile-application, mobile-development

So I'm doing some research and am a little lost as I don't have any experience in regards to the dev side of applications. I've got a few questions and would greatly appreciate some help:

1) Is there any full device encryption for Android mobile devices? I didn't see any 3rd party apps that did this but I can't believe this would be the case unless...

2) Do 3rd party apps have permission to do such a things? If not, can they encrypt personal files/folders?

3) Where can I go to find out more about the permissions of 3rd party apps?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

@Anoob Best advice for encryption is to ask you a question. Storage of data can be encrypted if you are using sqlyte database. That said you need to decide where you are saving that data. Android devices have internal and external storage (SD CARD)

Permissions has changed with the introduction of API level 23. Prior to Sdk 23 apps on the play store set permissions when they were downloaded. So if you do a search to read about this topic try to keep this in mind and look at current articles if your looking for code. In conjunction to permissions you need to consider what your minimum Sdk will be.

Here is some advice before asking questions do a lot of reading but much more important develop a written list of search terms and always use "example" in your search if you are looking for code and include the word "android" Java is used in a lot of other development languages.

Here is a high quality site with a lot of good tutorials and code
[Great Source](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-App-Permissions)

Welcome to Stack Overflow